# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. After replace from NodeJs to Website

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
```

I wrote the code for lessons on the Internet for the node js. But I need to do this for the site so I copied it. After running it gave me this problem (not with command `node app.js`, it starts in browser as default js code): `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Please tell me what can be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Check out this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/1540177

Answer (score 0):

In web browser we don't have the `require` function.

You can use the [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement or use cdn services like that:

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

importing directly like:

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis';
```

won't work on web browsers because the browser does not know where `'googleapis'` is.

Comment: Cannot use import statement outside a module. Why?

Comment: You need the script to be a module, this can be done with the `type='module'` attribute.
Read [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) from MDN

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' does not provide an export named 'google'`